# Rename xml element with child elements in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I try to rename element `<Visible>` to `<IsVisible>`, but this SELECT returns element Visible without child elements, how can I get Visible with UserId and RoleId elements?

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<FieldId>2200</FieldId>
<Visible xsi:type="UserRole">
   <UserId xsi:type="CurrentUserId" />
   <RoleId>26</RoleId>
</Visible>
</Root>';

SELECT @xml.query(N'let $nd:=(//*[local-name()="Visible"])[1]
                     return
                     <IsVisible> {$nd/@*}
                     {$nd/text()}
                     </IsVisible>
                    ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<FieldId>2200</FieldId>
<Visible xsi:type="UserRole">
   <UserId xsi:type="CurrentUserId" />
   <RoleId>26</RoleId>
</Visible>
</Root>';

SELECT @xml.query(N'let $nd:=(//*[local-name()="Visible"])[1]
                     return
                     <IsVisible> {$nd/@*}
                     {$nd/*}                     
                     </IsVisible>
                    ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use XQuery (FLWOR) or a simple replace

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<FieldId>2200</FieldId>
<Visible xsi:type="UserRole">
   <UserId xsi:type="CurrentUserId" />
   <RoleId>26</RoleId>
</Visible>
</Root>';
```

--Works, but will reorganise your namespace declarations

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd
                  ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT @xml.query(N'<Root>
                    {
                      for $nd in /Root/*
                      return
                      if(local-name($nd)!="Visible") then
                        $nd
                      else
                      <IsVisible>{$nd/@*}
                      {$nd/*}
                      </IsVisible>
                    } 
                    </Root> 
                    ');
```

--Might be easier here

```
SELECT CAST( 
            REPLACE(REPLACE(
            CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            ,'<Visible ','<IsVisible ')
            ,'</Visible>','</IsVisible>')
            AS XML)
```